# Spectral radius is at most the value of norm

Tags: normed-spaces

Let $M_n$ be the space of all $n\times n$ complex matrices and ||.|| be a matrix norm over $M_n$. If $A\in M_n$ then how to show that the spectral radius of A $\le||A||?$

Comment: Since this is a site that encourages and helps with learning, it is best if you show your own ideas and efforts in solving the question. Can you edit your question to add your thoughts and ideas about it?

Comment: It's in every single textbook. This is not your search engine.

Comment: Since I am clueless I don’t know what to add as my thoughts.

Comment: (Mis-)Using voluntary helpers at MSE as your search engine is rude, but I'm not interested in *your* identity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to check that if $|\lambda| > ||A||$, then $\lambda I_n - A$ is invertible.

**One way:**

This is true if and only if $I_n - \frac{1}{\lambda}A$ is invertible.  The norm of $\frac{1}{\lambda}A$ is $|\frac{1}{\lambda}| \cdot ||A|| < 1$.  So you are done if you can show:

> Lemma: If $||B|| < 1$, then $I_n - B$ is invertible.

Hint: geometric series.

**Another way**: All norms on $M_n(\mathbb{C})$ are equivalent, so choose any norm on $\mathbb{C}^n$, and choose $|| \cdot ||$ to be the operator norm on $M_n(\mathbb{C})$.  Then $$||A|| = \sup\limits_{0 \neq v} \frac{||Av||}{||v||}$$

If $\lambda I_n - A$ is not invertible, then there exists a nonzero $v$ such that $\lambda v = Av$.  For such $v$,

$$||A|| \geq \frac{||Av||}{||v||} = \frac{|\lambda| \cdot ||v||}{||v||} = |\lambda| $$